# Spring Integration. TCP Server Factory

Tags: tcp, spring-integration

probably is an easy way to do,

What I want to is:
I have a tcp server which listens to the incoming connection.
I would like to be informed somehow when a client connected.
TcpNetServerConnectionFactory has inside such information "Accepted connection ...".

There is TcpConnectionSupport class, however I cannot find a way how to use it. I am looking something similar to subscriber pattern.

Is there some way to do it?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you are asking. Could you possibly post the work that you have done like the code of your tcp server. What pieces are you using to integrate with Spring? Spring is a rather large project, what pieces of spring are you using?

Answer (score 0):

From one side it isn't clear how you want to implement `subscriber pattern`, if it is a Spring Integration out-of-the-box feature with `<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>`. When the new connection from client is established and client starts to send the data that component will be ready to receive it and convert to the `message` to send to the `channel` for further integration flow.

From other side there is an `ApplicationEvent` infrastructure, and when connection is open, the `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory` emits `TcpConnectionOpenEvent`. You can listen to this event using `<int-event:inbound-channel-adapter event-types="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpConnectionOpenEvent"/>`.
And again: it will be a message flow.